# "I read <more> books <more> than magazines." — parsing

Tags: parsing, comparative

**(1a)** *I read books more than magazines*. — correct
"*More*" in (1a) modifies "*read*".
**(1b)** *I read books more than I do/did magazines*. — correct
Since (1b) exists, then "*than*" in (1a) is the conjunction.
This conjunction in (1a) joins the clause "*I read books more*" and the clause "*magazines*" together.

**(2a)** *I read more books than magazines*. — correct
"*More*" in (2a) modifies "*books*".
**(2b)** *I read more books than I do/did magazines*. — incorrect
Since (2b) does not exist, then "*than*" in (2a) is the preposition.
The prepositional phrase "*than magazines*" in (2a) modifies "*more*" (although it seems strange to me).

Could you show me please all mistakes I did in my parsing?

Answer (score 3):

The initial clause in (1b) is "*I read books*", while "*I read books more*" is not a clause. "*more than I do*" is an adjectival phrase modifying "*magazines*". That (1b) is valid does not indicate how (1A) should be parsed.

Sentence (2b) is grammatically valid.

Comment: I think it would be better to say that in (1b) "than I do magazines" is complement of "more". In full (unreduced) it would be *"I read books more than I do read magazines".

Comment: Incidentally, "more" is never an adjective, but always either a determinative, as in "He made more mistakes", or an adverb as in "He behaved more tactfully than she did", and the OP's example 1b of course.